# How to generate page level access token programmatically

Tags: node.js, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

```
    var options = {
                method: 'post',
                json: true,
                url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/'+commentId+'/comments?message='+req.body.message+'&access_token={{ACCESSTOKEN}}'
            }
            request(options, function(error, response, body) {
                if(error){
                }
                console.log('posted reply successfully');
            });
```

Hi I using graph API to reply to comment on facebook pages of my customers (it is a SaaS product). Right now I am generating facebook page level access token for mine own and it's working fine for few minutes. But I want to generate page level access token programmatically, so that it does not expire and it is dynamic for different customer's facebook pages. Is there any way I can generate page level access token programmtically for my own facebook page?

Comment: You need a user access token first, to be able to get a page access token. Go read the documentation on expiration of access tokens, and how their lifetime can be extended.

Comment: @CBroe I have read the documentation. I know we need user access token first and then follow couple of steps.  I know that all . But I have no resource available on internet which tell me how can I generate user level access token programmatically, given that I have app ID and app secret

Comment: You have not found that, because it is of course not possible.

Comment: Yes. The only way to generate user access tokens is to send the user through the login flow.